# How to get lat long after arcgis mapview scroll in android?

Tags: android, geolocation, arcgis

I am using  Arcgis mapview Api in android.There is a pin we have added at the center of the screen. I want to get the coordinate for the location that comes under that pin when i scroll the map.Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution you are looking for hope it will work.

https://developers.arcgis.com/android/beta/sample-code/feature-layer-selection.htm

// get the point that was clicked and convert it to a point in map coordinates

```
Point clickPoint = mMapView.screenToLocation(new android.graphics.Point(Math.round(e.getX()), Math.round(e.getY())));
                int tolerance = 44;
                double mapTolerance = tolerance * mMapView.getUnitsPerPixel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [OnStatusChangeListener](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/event/OnStatusChangedListener.html) on your map and update Point to center. You can check below link for more help.

[How to add marker or graphics to MapView using ArcGIS android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041489/how-to-add-marker-or-graphics-to-mapview-using-arcgis-android-sdk)