# How do i show the marker at given position on google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an app using google map.In this i want to show marker at location which longitude latitude values fetch form server.How do i show marker at this fetched longitude and latitude value?
Following code fetch the longitude and latitude values from my server successfully, i want to show marker on google map with this fetch langitude and latitude.How do i do?

```
//java code
public class Location_Track1 extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "Location_Track1";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 1; //1 minute
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    private static final float SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 0.25F; //quarter of a meter
    Button btnFusedLocation;
    TextView tvLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    private ImageView mCurrentPointer;

    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;
//    private ArrayList<LatLng> points; //added
    private List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    Polyline line; //added

    TextView tv_mobno, tv_latitude, tv_longitude, tv_time;
    String getLatitude;
    String getLongitude;
    Button slocation;

    JSONArray result = null;

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String CON = "CON";
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;

    private String url ="";

    private static final String TAG_USER = "result";

    //   private static final String TAG_SNAME = "pseats";
    private static final String TAG_LONG = "longitude";
    private static final String TAG_LAT = "latitude";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "paddress";

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT); //added
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location_track);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");

        tv_mobno=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_mob);
        tv_latitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_latitude);
        tv_longitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_longitude);
        tv_time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_time);
        slocation=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_slocation);

        url = "http://example.in/gmap_track.php";

     //   points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();


        slocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               // new DownloadJSON().execute();
                new JSONParse().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Location_Track1.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {

                // Getting JSON Array
                result = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
                JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);


                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                String longt = c.getString(TAG_LONG);


                //Set JSON Data in TextView

                tv_latitude.setText(lat);
                tv_longitude.setText(longt);

            /*    double lat = c.getDouble(TAG_LAT);
                double longt = c.getDouble(TAG_LONG);

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, longt)).title("point");
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);*/


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can anyne suggest me How do i show json values of(latitude, longitude) fetching form server to google map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you commented out your code for adding the marker?
Try this :

```
// Storing  JSON item in a Variable
   String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
   String longt = c.getString(TAG_LONG);


//Set JSON Data in TextView

  tv_latitude.setText(lat);
  tv_longitude.setText(longt);

//Parse data to double
  double latD = Double.parseDouble(lat);
  double longtD = Double.parseDouble(longt);

  MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latD, longtD)).title("point");
  googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: it dosenot show any location by using above.Map simply shows blank.

Comment: how do i show fetched langitude and latitude values to marker?

Comment: by using this,  double latD = Double.parseDouble(lat);
  double longtD = Double.parseDouble(longt); doesnot get the values of langitude and latitude.

Comment: you initialize map with wrong method. try to read the link i give

Comment: when i add the munually values to marker option method then it shows the map.But values from double latD = Double.parseDouble(lat); double longtD = Double.parseDouble(longt);  doesn't getting.

Comment: Is there a way to offset the marker to the left or right of the `LatLng` location in pixels? I have a walker icon and it's centered on the person's body instead of the legs touching the street.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Sydney").snippet("The most populous city in Australia.").position(sydney));
    }
```

Comment: i want to show marker at given any (longitude, latitude)value this values i fetch from server.

Comment: Just Simple replace sydney (longitude, latitude) value to your lat/long value fetch from server

Answer (score 0):

You must use:
     GoogleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions);
watch this site and this Question also:
http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html

[code to add markers to map using android google maps v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194918/code-to-add-markers-to-map-using-android-google-maps-v2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo class, using which you can add Marker to given lat and long.

```
public class MarkerDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnMarkerClickListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.952854, 115.857342);
private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);
private static final LatLng BRISBANE = new LatLng(-27.47093, 153.0235);

private Marker mPerth;
private Marker mSydney;
private Marker mBrisbane;

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.marker_demo);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

/** Called when the map is ready. */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;

    // Add some markers to the map, and add a data object to each marker.
    mPerth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(PERTH)
            .title("Perth");
    mPerth.setTag(0);

    mSydney = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(SYDNEY)
            .title("Sydney");
    mSydney.setTag(0);

    mBrisbane = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(BRISBANE)
            .title("Brisbane");
    mBrisbane.setTag(0);

    // Set a listener for marker click.
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
}

/** Called when the user clicks a marker. */
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    // Retrieve the data from the marker.
    Integer clickCount = (Integer) marker.getTag();

    // Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
    if (clickCount != null) {
        clickCount = clickCount + 1;
        marker.setTag(clickCount);
        Toast.makeText(this,
                       marker.getTitle() +
                       " has been clicked " + clickCount + " times.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // Return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event and that we wish
    // for the default behavior to occur (which is for the camera to move such that the
    // marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one).
    return false;
}
```

}