# Marker on map after a button click in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to make a marker on my map application after a click event on my activity, I mean when I click on button "accident" a red marker is added to the map With current location coordinates

Thanks

Comment: put your code here

Comment: What did you try so far? Any effort? `on_click(Coords coords){setMarker(coords);}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your `onClickListener`:

```
GoogleMap map = ... // get a map.
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
   .title("San Francisco")
   .snippet("Population: 776733"));
```

For further reference, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195093/6416203).

Answer (score 0):

Inside:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap arg0) {
....
}
```

Create a setOnMapClickListener that sets a callback that's invoked when the map is tapped:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng destination) {

            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            options.position(destination);
            options.title("Lat=" + destination.latitude + ", Long=" + destination.longitude);
            Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
        }
    });
```