# How can I start a maps activity at a specific location inside my app?

Tags: android, google-maps

So I have a list of locations (inside a ListFragment) and their corresponding coordinates and I want to start a new map activity when one of them is pressed.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + locations[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent eventActivity = new Intent(getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(eventActivity);
}
```

Currently I have it so that when one of the items is clicked, it displays the name of the location, then opens a map to (0,0) within the app. How can I open the map to the coordinates that corresponds to the location (which I have)?

**Thanks to Ajeet Choudhary. Solved. Solution below.**

MapFragment.java

```
public class MapFragment extends ListFragment{

...

LatLng[] coordinates = new LatLng[] {
        new LatLng(..., ...),
        new LatLng(..., ...),
        new LatLng(..., ...),
        ...
};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MapAdapter(getActivity(), locations);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + locations[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent eventActivity = new Intent(getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
    eventActivity.putExtra("latlng", coordinates[position]);
    startActivity(eventActivity);
}
}
```

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker and move the camera.
    LatLng location = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("latlng");
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Marker"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
}
}
```

Comment: do you have Latlng of that particular location or address only?

Comment: Both. I have a list of location names, its physical address, and LatLng. The  location name and physical address are displayed in the list.

Comment: What is MainActivity? If it's your class than add corresponding code to question.

Comment: You mean MapsActivity? Its just a default google maps class i got from the example app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Latlng already have implemnted Parcable class, so put that into intent and send to your Map activity,get That Latlng from getIntent().getParcableExtra("your_key"), then there will be methods onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)(if you have implemented map there already) add your latlng to the Map ,see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44574391/7134908) for help.

Comment: In your code LatLng location = new LatLng(<Lat>,<Lng>); do you pas your latlng there??